C++ library passes incorrect / inconsistent data to flutter using dart:FFI
I have a Flutter application that uses a c++ library using the Dart:ffi package.
My c++ code listens for events whenever a barcode is scanned, this triggers a callback in Dart which then displays said barcode on the screen.
I am doing 2 things in my c++ code:

Logging it to a .txt file
Displaying it on the screen through a callback.

When logging the data to a .txt file it's always correct.
Whenever passing that same data to a callback that displays it on the screen there's 3 scenario's:

It is empty
It is correct
The first character is missing, in my flutter console it's missing on my screen it looks like []

There are no weird characters either it's a simple CODE128 barcode like LOREM;IPSUM
My current solution is having the callback read the data from the .txt file, but I am curious why it doesn't work with the callback.
Code samples;
Flutter:
typedef InitializeScannerFunc = Void Function(Pointer<NativeFunction<BarcodeCallback>>);
typedef InitializeScanner = void Function(Pointer<NativeFunction<BarcodeCallback>>);
typedef BarcodeCallback = Void Function(Pointer<Utf8>);

final InitializeScanner initializeScannerFunc = dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<InitializeScannerFunc>>('InitializeScanner').asFunction();
final Pointer<NativeFunction<BarcodeCallback>> barcodeCallbackPtr = Pointer.fromFunction<BarcodeCallback>(barcodeCallback);
final nativeCallable = NativeCallable<BarcodeCallback>.listener(barcodeCallback);

FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {    
        initializeScannerFunc(nativeCallable.nativeFunction);
    },
),              

C++
void invokeBarcodeCallback(const char* barcodeData) {
    // Call the callback function with the barcode data
    if (callbackFunc != nullptr) {
        std::string data = barcodeData;
        logMessage("invokeBarcodeCallback: " + data);
        callbackFunc(barcodeData); 
    }
}

Can provide more code samples if needed.
Edit: I haven't done c++ untill now to communicate with the scanner.

barcodeData != "" may not do what you're hoping for. It is a comparison of two pointers and not the data pointed to. How to check if String is empty in C may help if you must use a raw pointer, but I'd use a const std::string& and use the empty() function.

@RetiredNinja You're right, thanks for pointing this out. Updated my code. However any idea why it's not consistent with the data passed to flutter compared to logfile?

I don't know anything about how Flutter works but my guess would be the lifetime of the string passed to the callback ends before the callback uses it so what you log in the function is correct but the data becomes corrupted after that.

@RetiredNinja thanks a lot! This made me search in a different direction and I found a solution, instead of passing a pointer to my callback I now pass a buffer to my callback which workes perfectly.
